# UIButton with Image and caption (title)

Tags: xcode, uibutton

I have the problem if I add a image to a UIButton that the title is gone. I need a button with a caption below. Something like this:

[image]

Are there any solutions or custom views?

Comment: use a textView below image view inside linear layout and keep clicklistner for linear layout

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <AppCompatImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="your image" />

    <AppCompatTextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Your Lable is here" />
</LinearLayout>
```